# How to detect topics in arbitrary text file or data? not knowing number of topics beforehand

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, word2vec, lda

I have textual data that I want to discover topics it has, I used trained doc2vec on large corpus such as Wikipedia, but there is inconsistency in the results. Is there a better approach to discover topics.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Hierarchical Dirichlet Process as implemented in the `gensim` class `gensim.models.hdpmodel.HdpModel`. From the [gensim docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/hdpmodel.html):

> Unlike its finite counterpart, latent Dirichlet allocation, the HDP
>   topic model infers the number of topics from the data.

Comment: does this require training on any sort of text data prior? if yes, which corpus is recommended for general topic detection?

Comment: Training is done on a part of the corpus you are examining. HDP will infer the number and content of topics from that training data. If a trained topic model is applied to unrelated documents, one can usually not expect to get meaningful and interpretable results.

Comment: is there a link of example? i have 2 page news article that i want to detect topics it has.